# How to get Newsletter form shown in footer block?

Tags: magento2, newsletter, magento-community

I'm new to Magento. I'm using Magento 2 Community Edition and I'm trying to get the newsletter subscriber form in the footer, but for some reason, it doesn't appear.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by 'get', I thought you meant add it but as it's already there in the blank and Luma theme and the previous answer is pretty much correct I presume you want to move it so I'll base my answer on that.

**Quick answer:**

```
<move element="form.subscribe" destination="*DESTINATION-HERE*" />
```

The explanation:

### Find the block name

First you need to find the name of the block you want to move, to do this I searched all of Magento's module and theme XML files for 'newsletter', to do this I used the following search term `vendor/magento/**/frontend/**/*.xml`. *With enough experience you'll know off the top of your heard that it's subscribe.phtml so it does get easier with time.* This returned quite a few files, the one that is responsible for adding the footer newsletter block is `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`. This is the code that renders the block:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" before="-" template="subscribe.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

### Move the block

Now we know the block name, we can move it. To do this we use this code:

```
<move element="*BLOCK-NAME-TO-MOVE*" destination="*DESTING-BLOCK-OR-CONTAINER-NAME*" />
```

So inside `app/design/frontend/*PACKAGE-NAME*/*THEME-NAME*/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` we can move the block, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="form.subscribe" destination="content" />
    </body>
</page>
```

In the above example the newsletter signup form will be moved to the content, you can swap content with any block or container you wish to place it in.

### Screenshot

[image]

### If you did want to add it to a new theme:

If you did actually mean add it then paste the below code into `app/design/frontend/STORE-NAME/THEME-NAME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" before="-" template="subscribe.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi Ben , your solution works very well for my template ! Thank you for your time , now I'm trying to get working also the double minicart , I will let you know how it goes..

Answer (score 3):

if you are creating your own them in

```
view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

put tag like this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" before="-" template="subscribe.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

don't forget to clear your layout cache

hope this will work for you

Comment: Hi liyakat , I've aready tryed like this , cleared the cache , but still nothing..

Comment: did you configure you theme perfectly. it should work to call newsletter in footer

Comment: yes it should be configured ok , I'm using Venustheme - Yume by the way..

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to move the block rather than redefine it?

Comment: my purpose to give this for new them not to change place :)

Comment: Yeah I think the question isn't very clear, or I'm being stupid :P

Comment: @liyakat How to display Newsletter Subscriber block in cms page, i did cms static block added : {{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}} after this go to cms page added cms static block as a  widget : {{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="63"}}, still my page empty, how to display Newsletter Subscriber block in cms page?

Comment: use this in to your CMS block :{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}