# How to have 2 Shopping Carts on the home page?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping

I'm using Venustheme - Yume theme , and what I want to do is to add another Shopping cart , in the top bar , and the normal one have it hidden on the desktop version , and when it goes mobile , hide the top bar one , and display the normal one. My problem is I'm new to Magento , and I don't know how to add, or where or what to call , to have another one in the top bar. Does anyone have any idea what I should do ?

Comment: I wouldn't advise duplicating code to achieve this, is there no way you could do it with CSS? How come you need two checkouts?

Comment: Cause I need it in different parts of the website , on desktop should be in the top bar , and on mobile should be inline with the menu.. so I hide the one for desktop and I display the one for mobile when I go mobile , and reverese when desktop..

Comment: You will need to find where the block is defined, and use the same code to create the block with another name. If you have any problems let me know and I'll provide a full answer with examples.

Comment: I have tryed to copy the content from the .phtml cart file , into the header.phtml , but it doesn't show up.. An example would be great ! Thank you for your time !

Comment: It will need to be the XML block that is copied. No problem, I will hopefully have it over to you in a few hours. If I haven't got back to you by Monday please give me a reminder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Adding the block

The XML for adding the minicart can be found in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`, it is:

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart.footer" as="minicart" template="cart/minicart.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

You will need to add this to the relevant place in your theme, in my example I added it within `<referenceContainer name="footer">` inside `app/design/frontend/PartyShowroom/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

**You will also need a unique name, so change `name="minicart"` to something else, like `name="minicart.mobile"` or whatever is suitable for you.**

### Screenshot

You can see my minicart in the usual place, and also in the footer (left of the newsletter signup)

[image]

### Problems

This will render the minicart icon and dropdown, but there is extra work to get it looking good and fully functional. For example when I click on one minicart the other is also actived, this may not be a problem for you if you are completely hiding the other one.

Seems there's also some CSS issues as both the cart dropdowns appear in the same place.

[image]

So this isn't a full solution to your problem, but it answers your question and should hopefully provide you with enough to get what you're after.

### Update - Fix the mobile cart dropdown appearing in the same place as the desktop cart dropdown.

This is down to line 39 (`"appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]"`) of `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml`.

As we need this template for the desktop we'll need to duplicate it and edit it. I duplicated it and renamed it to minicart-mobile.phtml and placed it in `app/design/frontend/STORE-NAME/THEME-NAME/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart`. Then change line 39 to the class/ID you want the dropdown to be appended to, for example `"appendTo":".footer",`

Then edit the XML that we added in the **adding the block** section above, change the template from minicart.phtml to **minicart-mobile.phtml** or whatever you choose to name the template. This will then render the dropdown separately to the desktop, and in a different location.

Comment: Thank you for the example Ben , I will try it out and let you know ! Just one more question , I posted it yesterday , but haven't got any result , tryed many ways to fix it , but no result , I will link it to you here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111910/how-to-get-newsletter-form-shown-in-footer-block  Best regards, Alex C

Comment: I've answered that question now, I hope both answers work for you :D

Comment: Hi Ben , as you said , this solve part of what I'm trying to get , thank you for your time again ! One issue I'm having is that the search and cart is working properly only on one , what I mean is that when I click the cart on the mobile version , it doesn't popup the window because the other one is hidden , do you have any ideea to get that working ?

Comment: If it's hidden with CSS you may be able to display again by targeting an active class? Or possibly write some JS along the lines of when the mobile cart is clicked, display the dropdown. You may need to add some classes/IDs to the markup to target it this way.

Comment: The problem is that it also comes out in the first form place , and not in the second's form place..

Comment: I've added a fix for that to the bottom of my answer. It might be better to split further tasks into separate questions as my answer is getting out of hand :P

Comment: You could also look at using JS to move the element based on the browser width - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_js.html

Comment: I've almost got it working , I have also changed the data-block fields minicart to maxicart , and I have also changed <a class="action showcart" to <a class="action showcartm" , everything works fine now but the close button of the popup windows , if I click outside the window , it closes , but not if I click the X button , trying to figure out this now , thank you again !

Comment: If you can't figure it out you could add some JS to manually close it with the close icon. It's no problem, if the answer is correct for you please mark it as answered :D

Comment: you mean by adding a function on the button ? where do I find the code of the button ? sure by the way , now I mark it as answered !

Comment: Yeah, this is out of scope of the question so I can't really add it to this answer. You need to add a script that detects when you click on the close icon, and then sets display none or something similar on the cart dropdown. I recommend using require.js to add scripts by the way. If you're unsure how to do this and there are no questions about it on here feel free to ask it and I'll answer it on there.

Comment: Ok I got that , now I'm trying to do the same thing with the search form , I have already duplicated the phtml file and everything , but this one doesn't have the data-block.. here is the properly question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112703/duplicated-the-search-form-but-works-properly-only-on-one

Comment: In Magento 2.1.3 this solution doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Guys, I managed to make it working in my end. but except for the remove item button in the second copy of minicart it will not work instead it will also close. I hope you can help me thanks

Comment: @MazeStricks Can you ask a new question and post your code please? It's hard to help with comments alone